# How to query all rows that are due the next business day?

Tags: sql

If it helps, I'm using BytePro which I believe is using T-SQL based on the statement they've generated.

I'm having an issue where when I try retrieving data, I need to switch based on the day of the week. (current day being today's date using `GetDate()`).

M-T statement:

```
convert(varchar(10), [Status.SchedFundingDate], 112) <= convert(varchar(10), getdate() + 1, 112)
```

F statement:

```
convert(varchar(10), [Status.SchedFundingDate], 112) <= convert(varchar(10), getdate() + 3, 112)
```

I'd like to combine the two to automate the switch but I get a problem with

```
CAST(CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) = 'Friday' 
             AND [Status.SchedFundingDate] <= GETDATE() + 3 
           THEN 1
        WHEN [Status.SchedFundingDate] <= GETDATE() + 1
           THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END AS BIT)
```

I get an error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'

Comment: Try changing your GETDATE() + # to DATEADD(DAY,#,GETDATE())

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Same error as last time unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

this is the right syntax :

```
CAST(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) = 'Friday' 
             AND [Status].[SchedFundingDate] <= DATEADD(DAY, 3 , GETDATE())
           THEN 1
        WHEN [Status].[SchedFundingDate] <=  DATEADD(DAY, 1 , GETDATE())
           THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END AS BIT)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cc4ac9048f3e902fb2f81b3b1f80d836)*

Comment: @razimovom that was a leftover , oh the brackets are wrong , see updated asnwer

Comment: I have the same problem still. I'm not sure if it's even T-SQL at this point.

Comment: @razimovom then its not from this piece of code